# how to turn off navigation in tabnavigator

Tags: react-native

[image: my app]

I want user to set preferences first and then be able to navigate the app.
I have nested stack inside tabnvaigator is there any way to disable other tabs and prompt user to set preferences first

tabnavigator code

```
 const tab=createBottomTabNavigator()
    return (
        <tab.Navigator  
            initialRouteName="profile"
            tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#0000A0',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            keyboardHidesTabBar:true

          }}>
            <tab.Screen  name="personal" component={personalNav}
            options={{
                tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>{ return <Icon name='person-outline' size={size} color={color} />;}
            }}/>
            <tab.Screen  name="general" component={genRecomNav}
            options={{
                tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>{ return <Icon name='explore' size={size} color={color} />;}
            }}/>
            <tab.Screen  name="profile" component={profileNav}
            options={{
                tabBarIcon:({color,size})=>{ return <Icon name='fingerprint' size={size} color={color} />;}
            }}/>
        </tab.Navigator>
    )
```

```
stacknavigator code
```

```
const profileNav = createStackNavigator();
    return (

        <profileNav.Navigator   headerMode="none" screenOptions={
            {
              gestureEnabled:false,

              cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
              transitionSpec:{
                  open:TransitionSpecs.FadeInFromBottomAndroidSpec ,
                  close:TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
              }
            }} >
            <profileNav.Screen name="profileMain" component={profileMain}/>
            <profileNav.Screen name="preference" component={preference}/>
             <profileNav.Screen name="preferenceApp" component={preferenceApp}/>
            <profileNav.Screen name="preferenceTopic" component={preferenceTopic}/> 
        </profileNav.Navigator>

    )
```

Comment: You will probably need to show some code. At least your tab definition.

Comment: @artcorpse updated with code